# JPA Query for validating date and if number of days > 50 since the date

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

I have a sql table called Order. There is a column, `lastDT` which is the last updated date and I want to find out the orders that has been more than 35 days since that date. I want to compare it with the current date.

In Oracle SQL Developer, the query I have gotten is this:

```
select * 
from items 
WHERE TO_DATE(SYSDATE+1) - TO_DATE(LAST_UPDATE_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD') > 50;
```

In Java Code inside a method which is obviously wrong:

```
public ItemSpec byLastUpdateDT(Date lastDT) {
    String query = "Select o from ItemData o WHERE o.lastDT > 50";

    return this;

}
```

How can I write it such that I can take the last date in as a parameter inside the method, and use it to find the difference in number of days with the current date, specifically more than 50 days?

I am trying to retrieve the items and its fields that that has been declared in Item class (not shown).

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public ItemSpec byLastUpdateDT(Date lastDT) {
    String query = "Select o from StockData o WHERE o.lastDT <= sysdate - 50";

    return this;
}
```